# Moving an object (UIButton) through a circular path by keeping the parent view static

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uiviewanimation

How do I move some buttons into a circular path (using the center of an circular UIView) by 45 degree each time any of the buttons is clicked? You can say it's just like JOG WHEEL.

Comment: It sounds like you want to rotate the container view.

Comment: no...not the container...if i do that...the layout of the buttons also changed...i mean the text or image on the button flips...

now i can rotate the entire container...but because of that the layout of the button also changed...

Comment: So you are saying it's actually *not* like a Jog wheel?

Comment: pretty much...i just want those buttons to move across the circular path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a `CGPathRef` that contains the path along which you want to animate the view.
2. Create a `CAKeyframeAnimation`.
3. Assign the path to the `animation.path` property.
4. Add the animation to the view's layer.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry i am late. Actualy i did in that way. But i feel a fail to initialize that path in proper way. Please do help me. First problem is the Button is rotating but beyond that view(i used CGPathAddArc. Where center is the center point of a UIView around which i want to rotate) and second problem is i failed to initialize the new frame of that button. Code snippet is given bellow. Sorry for formatting. Thanks agin.

Comment: - (CAAnimation*)pathAnimation;
{
   CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, tempView.center.x,tempView.center.y, tempView.frame.size.width/2,0,45*M_PI/180, YES);
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [animation setPath:path];
    [animation setDuration:3];
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    [animation setAutoreverses:NO];
    CFRelease(path);
    return animation;
}
Then [myButton.layer addAnimation:[self pathAnimation] forKey:@"curveAnimation"];